# Reset variable in another SFC

Tags: plc

I am working on a PLC program (using CodeSys) consisting of several SFCs. One SFC is counting rising edges of a button. I want to be able to reset this counter even from anther SFC. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking on the wrong site as this isn't an electronics question. However, the simplest solution would be to create a global variable, "CountResetOneShot", trigger that from whatever event you want and use contacts of it in any program block that needs it.